# Is there a way to wrap the placeholder text for small devices?

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

I need a help on wrapping the placeholder text when the device width is smaller than the placeholder length , so that all the placeholder text is visible to the user.

Please help me achieve this .

Thanks in advance

Stackblitz link : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vudqqs

screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/5MB58.png

Comment: please add your code not link

Comment: Does this answer your question? [change the size of placeholder text to fit when on mobile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45189240/change-the-size-of-placeholder-text-to-fit-when-on-mobile)

Comment: Hi @לבנימלכה , I have used only bootstrap classes . I haven't added anything in custom css . pre-wrap is one solution . But I'm just wondering how to get the best use of it

Answer (score 0):

Please try this and check

```
::-webkit-input-placeholder { 
  white-space:pre-line;  
  position:relative;
  top:-7px;

}
```

For wrapping the place holder text..

Comment: I already tried this . When the placeholder is short , the placeholder should be vertically centered . so we cannot use top: -7px

Comment: use @media quries and change the height or line-height for the input box